# Set pythonpath in intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea

Where is the PYTHONPATH set in Intellij community edition 15.X?

Following shows where I have already looked:

`Python interpreter`:

[image]

`Python SDK`:

[image]

`Global Libraries`:

[image]

So .. I can not find where to set the environment variables for `$PYTHONPATH`.  Funny thing - I recall having been able to do so in version 14 Ultimate Edition. Is this a CE version difference?

Answer (score 17):

I arrive some four years late to this party ;-) but this is the solution I have just found to incorporate arbitrary directories in my project to the IntelliJ path for execution and import inspection:

***TL;DR: The only thing you need to do is marking the directory containing the module you want to import as a 'Sources Root'***

Some additional explanation: I was trying to make work an old LiEclipse project inside Intellij CE last edition and it was giving me hell because I couldn't find a way to modify the PYTHONPATH to add the folder containing the "*DegreeDistributionsForGraphs*" module I need

[image]

In the end I found it is as easy as marking the folder as a 'Sources Root', from that moment on import and execution resolution works properly

[image]

I'm using the last IntelliJ CE available (in fact downloaded today)

[image]

Comment: Thx .. but I need to add `pyspark` libraries that are not even in this project physically.

Comment: I have just included that 'pysparkx' library by adding the line 'import pysparkx' to my file and using the offered option 'install package pyspark'.I would paste an image but it seems it is not possible in comments. Regards

Comment: I need to include a specific directory (local spark installation). I do need to specifically use `PYTHONPATH` .  I will upvote as useful but this is still not a direct answer to the question.

Comment: Now I got you. You are right: mine is in fact not a direct response to your question. Thanks for upvoting anyway ;-)

Comment: Even though the title mentions IntelliJ this also works for CLion.

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you are looking for is under `Project structure->Modules->Dependencies->Module SDK` which will be the python interpreter setup within `Platform Settings->SDKs`. You are also able to add additional paths to the Python SDK which I believe acts as the `$PYTHONPATH`.

Python Console:

I currently have CE16.1, however, it may be similar. I was able to find information under `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console` within the Preferences to set different options such as Environment variables, Interpreter options etc. Intellij's page on [Python console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/python-console.html?origin=old_help&search=Python%20consol) may help also.

Comment: That's interesting: may be useful when/if i use python console. But I need the variable set for the interpreter /editor as well: what you mention here does not affect them.

Comment: @javadba Are you trying to set it so that it autocompletes/recognizes the modules you are using? Have you also checked to make sure you have your PYTHONPATH set for your system environment variables using `echo $PYTHONPATH` or `echo %PYTHONPATH%` (Windows)?

Comment: Yes PYTHONPATH is set appropriately in .bashrc and is reflected in bash. I do remember it is necessary to set PYTHONPATH explicitly inside intellij: but I can no longer discover how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the project ---> `"Open Module settings"`

`"Project Settings"` ---> `"Modules"`
Click on the project

Click `"+Add Content Root"`

Add the path of the desired pythonpath reference.
After adding it, mark it as `'Resources'`

Comment: I'll mark this as helpful but I had reasons to set the actual variable, not just add another entry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new Library (or Global Library) of type Java and add your path twice, under both Classes and Sources.

This will be used for imports and running tests.